# How to make selection (choose one of the two strings with select input in html) with Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to make the user only choose between two strings, Internal or Consigned, to be inserted into the InternalConsigned column of a database. How do I do that?
This is my current code:

Equipment.cs model class:

```
    public class Equipment
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Equipment Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Amount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department? Department { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string InternalConsigned { get; set; }

        public DateTime EOLDate { get; set; }

    }
```

Create action method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Amount,Status,DepartmentId,InternalConsigned,EOLDate")] Equipment equipment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(equipment);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["DepartmentId"] = new SelectList(_context.Departments, "Id", "Name", equipment.DepartmentId);
            return View(equipment);
        }
```

Create.cshtml:

```
@model Equipment

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h4>Equipment</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Amount" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Amount" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Status" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Status" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Status" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DepartmentId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="DepartmentId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DepartmentId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="InternalConsigned" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="InternalConsigned" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="InternalConsigned" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EOLDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EOLDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EOLDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know I have to use the select tag in the View, but I'm not sure what to write in the Controller.

Comment: What issue you are having now? So basically you would prefer either `Internal` or `Consigned` to be inserted on `InternalConsigned` perperty value right? If so why can't we made it as dropdown?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yes I want it to be a dropdown and the selected string will be inserted into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand your question, You want to write a dropdown list with two options `Internal` or `Consigned`, So you can refer to this simple demo, Hope it can help you.

```
            List<SelectListItem> test = new List<SelectListItem>();
            test.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Internal ", Value = "Internal " });
            test.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Consigned", Value = "Consigned" });
            ViewData["demo"] = test;
```

Then in the view:

```
<select asp-for="InternalConsigned" asp-items="@ViewBag.demo"></select>
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: I followed your code but it doesn't work, where should I write that list? I wrote it in my Create action method.

Comment: Create action `HttpGet` method. Do you get any error?

Comment: My mistake, I wrote it in `HttpPost`. It's working now, Thank You!